# Change a list of numbers with decimals to a list of integers only

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

So I came across this problem of a number list having decimal numbers in between integers, and I would like to change them to a list of just integers.

So there is a list that looks like this :

- 1
- 1
- 2
- 2.1
- 2.2
- 3
- 3
- 3.1
- 3.1
- 4

I want to keep the group of the same numbers but just want to renumber them with integers, so the end result would look something like this:

- 1
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 5
- 6
- 6
- 7

Or this is a screenshot of an example,

[image: My Goal]

After some trial and errors, I ask for help.

The logic of renumbering is

1. Numerical order
2. Rows of the same numbers need to have the same number

And of course, this is just a small example of the actual task I need to do that has like over thousands of entries.

What macro would be able to do that?

Comment: there is a formula in Excel with this purpose: [INT()](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/int-function-a6c4af9e-356d-4369-ab6a-cb1fd9d343ef)

Comment: Please explain the logic of the conversion, because now you show 3 becomes 3, then 3.1 becomes 4, then 4 becomes 5 ...

Comment: @Damian yes but changing decimals numbers just to integers isn't enough, I want to renumber them in order as shown in the screenshot

Comment: @TomBrunberg so I would call this as "renumbering" rather than "conversion" because I'm not converting the original numbers with a certain logic, it's more like renumbering them in numerical order, making sure the rows of the same numbers get the same numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a formula, like this one:

```
=IF(A1=A2,B1,B1+1)
```

The results are like the following screenshot:

[image]

For your information: "B1" equals `=A1` (so you must start with an integer), "B2" equals the mentioned formula and you just drag it down.

Comment: I didn't even need a macro xD Thank you very much!